# KeyError: 'col' 'occured at index col' during apply function

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
  target  |  date |  US_midi | UK_midi | NL_midi | BE_midi | FR_midi | SP_midi | PT_midi | SU_midi | COL_MIDI
    23       1970       1         0         0          0        0        0          0         0               0
    34       1970       0         0         1          0        0        0          0         0               0
    34       1970       0         1         1          0        0        0          0         0               0
```

Currently the `COL_MIDI` value is set to 0, but I want to change it to one if **any** of the `*_MIDI` columns, **except the `US_midi` and `SU_midi` variables** are set to 1

So in the example the last 2 rows would get a `1` for the `COL_MIDI` variable

To this end I wrote the following function:

```
def col_checker(x):
    col_list = ['UK_midi', 'NL_midi', 'BE_midi', 'FR_midi', 'SP_midi', 'PT_midi']
    for nation in col_list:
        if x[nation] != 0:
            x['COL_MIDI'] = 1
```

Which I run with the following command:

```
df['COL_MIDI'] = df.apply(col_checker)
```

Yet everytime I encounter the following error (and the values stay at 0)

```
('UK_midi', 'occurred at index target')
```

I tried resetting the index (did not work) and I inspected both the dataframe, and saved the dataframe as a csv to then inspect it - but could not detect any anomalies. All columns have equal length and everything, so I am not sure how the index could have gotten messed up, nor why it is preventing my script from running.

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You may need `axis=1`  in your `df.apply(` (not tested)

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks for your response! I normally dont use 'apply'  functions against the entire dataframe, so using the axis did not occur to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simpler way to achieve what you want

```
col_list = ['UK_midi', 'NL_midi', 'BE_midi', 'FR_midi', 'SP_midi', 'PT_midi']
df['COL_MIDI'] = (df[col_list].sum(axis=1) > 0) * 1
```